# How can I return only values from dataframe upon filtering in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to return only the row values (without column header or index column) based upon filter query. I am trying to write a function to this and have this so far:

```
def selector(name):
  return df.loc[df['name'] == name][['name','color','number']].reset_index(drop = True)
```

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  | Name  | Color  |  Number  |
0 | Mo    | Red    |    4     |
1 | Sue   | Blue   |    2     |
2 | Mat   | Red    |    6     |
3 | Mo    | Green  |    3     |
```

If I run my function:

```
selector('Mo')
```

I want it to return something like this:

```
0 | Mo   |  Red   |  4
3 | Mo   |  Green |  3
```

But instead return something like this:

```
  | Name |  Color | Number
 1| Mo   |  Red   |  4
 3| Mo   |  Green |  3
 Name: df, dtype: object
```

How can I alter my function so that I can retrieve the results in the format that I would like?

Comment: Isn't `selector('Mo')` returning that already? Or do you mean without the column names? If so, chain that with `tolist()` or `to_numpy()`.

Comment: tolist() almost works, but it has brackets around the returned value. I want just the values. So if I rewrote my function to call for the two highest numbers It would return:


            | Mat | Red | 6
            | Mo  | Red | 4

Comment: You seem to be asking about **string representation** of a specific data, which is not unreasonable, but still something you would be able to do via trial/error with double `for` loop.

Comment: Do you want that representation? Does the type of returned values has any importance?

Comment: I was assigned to report the results in this format based upon a query such as the given example above. The reader that will take my input is specific and will flag it if there are column names or index values included.

Comment: I looked into string representation, which seems rather dense. I don't believe that is within my wheelhouse at this point in my Python learning path :/

Comment: @brandooo23 did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def selector(name):
    return df.query('Name.eq(@name)')

selector('Mo')
>>>

    Name    Color   Number
0   Mo      Red     4
3   Mo      Green   3
```

Comment: I apologize, I meant to add the table of what my output looks like. I basically only want the rows' values. I don't want the index, column names or object info at the bottom. So I do not want it to show "Name", "Color" or "Number".

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code snippet will clarify your doubts.
Let me know if you have any further questions about it.

```py
import doctest

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def selector(df: pd.DataFrame, name: str) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    >>> data = pd.DataFrame({
    ...     'name': ['Mo', 'Sue', 'Mat', 'Mo'],
    ...     'color': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Green'],
    ...     'number': [4, 2, 6, 2]
    ... })
    >>> selector(data, 'Mo')
    array([['Mo', 'Red', 4],
           ['Mo', 'Green', 2]], dtype=object)
    """
    condition = df["name"] == name
    col_names = ["name", "color", "number"]
    return df.loc[condition][col_names].values


if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def selector(name):
  return df.loc[df['Name'] == name].style.hide_index().hide_columns()
```

Output:

[image]